# cannot access excel file using Pandas Python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hi i am trying to run my python code through several excel files and get the data from each file and save into a data frame. Here is my code..

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd


path =r'C:\Users\user1\Desktop\test'
files = os.listdir(path)
files_xls = [f for f in files if f[-3:] == 'xls']   
df = pd.DataFrame()
for f in files_xls:
    filename, ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    data = pd.read_excel(f, filename)
    df = df.append(data)

a = df.describe()
print (a)
```

and i am getting this error.. the first file in the folder i am working at is test.xls

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 20, in <module>
    data = pd.read_excel(f, filename)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-   packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 170, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 227, in __init__
    self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(io)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 395, in open_workbook
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.xls'
```

Comment: I checked your code with the line `data = pd.read_excel(f, filename)` changed to `data = pd.read_excel(f)` and it worked normally. Why use the `filename` argument?

Comment: i tried that..it gives me the same error also

Comment: Did you try the solution below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import os
import pandas as pd

path =r'C:\Users\user1\Desktop\test'
os.chdir(path)
files = os.listdir(path)
files_xls = [f for f in files if f[-3:] == 'xls']   
df = pd.DataFrame()
for f in files_xls:
    data = pd.read_excel(f)
    df = df.append(data)

a = df.describe()
print (a)
```

Comment: You could put it in the first line before the `path` variable. And by the way, use `data = pd.read_excel(f)` instead of `data = pd.read_excel(f, filename)`

Answer (score 0):

File is not found because you are calling a relative reference to Excel file and the Python script may not reside in same folder as the file. Hence, use absolute reference which is not contigent to location of called script. You can do so by concatenating the path to file name using `os.path.join()`:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

path = r'C:\Users\user1\Desktop\test'

files = os.listdir(path)
files_xls = [f for f in files if f[-3:] == 'xls']   

dfList = []
for f in files_xls:
    data = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(path, f))
    dfList.append(data)

df = pd.concat(dfList)
```

Alternatively, use glob which avoids check on extension and retrieves full path of files:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

path = r'C:\Users\user1\Desktop\test'
files_xls = glob.glob(path+'\*.xls')

dfList = []
for f in files_xls:
    data = pd.read_excel(f)
    dfList.append(data)

df = pd.concat(dfList)
```